# How to test if the difference between two percentages is statistically significant?

Tags: p-value, percentage

Help, please! My question seems so simple but I can't manage to find an answer.

I have 150 students, I made them report their emotional state when reading a book and when watching a movie. The results look like this: $60$%  of students experienced excitement when reading the book, $70$% of students experienced excitement when watching the movie.

How to tell if the difference is statistically significant?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  It seems that your students both read a book and saw a movie, so how can you disentangle  the two effects?  Assuming you meant something like "I have $150$ students who only read a book, and another $150$ who only saw a movie and I got the given results" then the test would be "assume that there is a common probability, say $.65$, which predicts success and which is independent of books and movies.  Is the result plausible within some preset range?

Comment: To be clear... is this a hypothetical scenario?  Are the students who learned with the book the *same* students who learned with the movie?  If so, was it the same material being taught by the book and movie?  If so... it *sounds* like you are asking "60% passed if they learned the material only once.  70% passed if they learned the material twice" and the fact that there was a difference in book vs movie is perhaps irrelevant.  The way it is phrased, it sounds like a very poorly designed experiment.

Comment: As you can see from the comments, we can't sort out what you are asking.  It doesn't sound like you conducted the trial in a way that would permit the analysis you want.  In any case, please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: @lulu @JMoravitz; Thank you for your questions and sorry for being unclear. I modified the actual scenario to simplify the question but I made it worse. 

the experiment was actually asking students to report on their experiences when reading a book, then when watching a movie. In the first scenario, 60% of students experienced excitement, in the second 70% of students experienced excitement. I want to see if the difference is significant.

Comment: If you are using a single group of students, then there is not much to be said.  Perhaps we are seeing something about the film experience over reading, perhaps we are seeing that the second pass through the subject matter was more rewarding than the first.  Add to that the fact that $60\%$ and $70\%$ are pretty close, and I wouldn't want to even try to draw any conclusions.

Comment: What if we suppose it is a textbook exercise and forget about the carryover effect? What would be the right statistical method to use?